# Codeigniter return password in profile?

Tags: codeigniter, passwords

(This is for a codeigniter project)
I'm developing a user-profile page, that lists the user's profile very similarly to Stackoverflow's profile page.

I have a simple echo command in the view file:

```
<? echo $members->row()->password?>
```

This displays the md5 string. (I'm not too familiar with terms--I'm a beginner).

How can I display the password (like a password field) in the correct form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the whole point of MD5, you can't decrypt.  You can only match encrypted strings together to see if they are equal.

[Wikipedia: MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Comment: Hahaha...okay. :)  Would you just recommend having an "edit password" link?

Comment: Depends on how you want to do it.  If you are sold on MD5, then you need to provide a "Reset Password" link where that functionality only allows you to create a new password after some kind of verification process (usually email)

Comment: You shouldnt just use md5. You should introduce a salt into the md5 also. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 and here http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-password-security